# Is there any query (SOQL, APEX) that we could run that would determine objects linked to inactive users

Tags: apex, soql, profile, permissions

I am new to salesforce development

Is there any way so that i can have all those objects(in case possible record too) linked to a user is having.

How it is possible via apex or soql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run queries of this for from Apex or in the "Query Editor" of the "Developer Console":

```
select Id, Name from Account where OwnerId in (select Id from User where IsActive = false)
```

But you'll need to figure out all the object types you are interested in and run a query for each. Note that when objects are in master-detail relationship, you only need to consider the object at the top of the master-detail chain.

SOQL is a bit different to SQL: take a look at e.g. [Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) to see what can be done.

Comment: Its fine regarding the query but is there any posssibility for getting all the object user have the access through SOQL/APEX using describe and related. As in this case the maximum thing a person can have is the profile of that user

Comment: @riteshjaiswal You can add a further profile filter but that would probably require two queries and Apex code to connect them together. You can find all the SObjects and filter to keep only the master objects using describe calls. But then you will have to use [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to do a query for each one in the pattern shown in the answer. Might take 50 lines of Apex.

Comment: thanx for the solution just need to add something more is the SOQL query like this System.assertEquals(2, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = a.Id ALL ROWS]);      to get all records owned by the user